# jQuery-ui autocomplete causes validation to fail if result is null

Tags: jquery-ui, autocomplete, null, asp.net-mvc-4

Long day and I'm still beating my head against the desk over this one.  I think I've read every jQuery ui autocomplete post here on stack overflow as well as most of the jQuery ui documentation.

The Problem:

I have a form in an asp.net mvc 4 application.  The form is for submitting a timesheet/work ticket.  The user selects a project and based upon that project an autocomplete field for work order number is enabled.  If the user chooses and existing work order number for the project, I populate two additional inputs with information about the work order.  I need to allow the user to type in a completely new work order with out selecting an autocomplete suggested work order and still have the form validate.  The problem is that validation fails if I do not select a suggestion from the autocomplete.

The jQuery-ui documentation does show that the methods close, disable, and destroy available to be used but I'm not finding a good example of how to use them and which would actually be best to use in my situation.  Also it might be worth noting that I am using jQuery-ui 1.9

The error I get:

*System.Data.Entity.Validation.DbEntityValidationException: Validation failed for one or     more entities. See 'EntityValidationErrors' property for more details.*

The error points to the line of code on my controller where I call _db.SaveChanges();

```
        if ( ModelState.IsValid )
        {
            _db.WorkTickets.Add(workticket);
            _db.SaveChanges();
        }
```

The model state is valid and I have no nulls trying to be saved.  My model does allow nulls on a few fields but in this case all fields are complete.

The form works great if I choose an existing work order from the autocomplete widget or if I leave it blank.  It only fails if I type in a new work order.  I have set a break point and verified that the model does have the value I typed in for work ticket.WONumber before calling save changes.

Here is my jQuery.

```
$(document).ready(function () {

    $("#ProjectID").change(function () {
        var id = $(this).val();
        var results = "result";

        var source1 = "Project/QuickCCSearch?project=" + id;
        $("#ChargeCode").autocomplete({ source: source1 });
        $("#ChargeCode").attr("disabled", false)

        var source2 = "Project/QuickPOSearch?project=" + id;
        $("#PONumber").autocomplete({ source: source2 });
        $("#PONumber").attr("disabled", false)

        var source3 = "Project/QuickWOSearch?project=" + id;
        $("#WONumber").attr("disabled", false)
        $("#WONumber").autocomplete({
            source: function (request, response) {
                $.ajax({
                    url: source3,
                    data: request,
                    success: function (data) {
                        response(data);
                        if (data.length === 0) {
                            $("#WONumber").attr("check", false);
                        }
                    }
                });
            },
            change: function () {
                if ($("#WONumber").attr("check") != false) {
                    $.getJSON("Project/JobLocation", { wo: $("#WONumber").val() },
                                function (data) {
                                    $("#JobLocation").val(data);
                                });

                    $.getJSON("Project/JobDescription", { wo: $("#WONumber").val() },
                                function (data) {
                                    $("#JobDescription").val(data);
                                });
                }
            }
        });

        $.getJSON("WorkTicket/GetClient/", { id: id },
            function (data) {
                $("#Client").html(data);
            });

        $.getJSON("WorkTicket/GetClientRep/", { id: id },
            function (data) {
                $("#ClientRep").html(data);
            });

        $.getJSON("WorkTicket/GetManager/", { id: id },
            function (data) {
                $("#Manager").html(data);

            });

    });

})
```

Edit:
Here is my Html

```
@model WorkTicket

@{
ViewBag.Title = "Create";
}
<article>
<div class="linearBg1">
    Create Daily Work Ticket
</div>
<br />
@using (Html.BeginForm()) {
    @Html.ValidationSummary(true)
    <div class="linearBg1">
        General Information
    </div>
    <div class="section-span-body">
        <table>
            <tr class="empTableRowBody2">
                <th class="empTableRowBody2">
                    @Html.LabelFor(Model => Model.DateWorked)
                </th>
                <th class="empTableRowBody2" colspan="2">
                    @Html.LabelFor(Model => Model.ProjectName)
                </th>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    @Html.EditorFor(Model => Model.DateWorked)
                </td>
                <td colspan="2">
                    @Html.DropDownList("ProjectID")
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr class="empTableRowBody2">
                <th class="empTableRowBody2">
                    Client
                </th>
                <th class="empTableRowBody2">
                    Client Rep
                </th>
                <th class="empTableRowBody2">
                    Manager
                </th>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <div id="Client"></div>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <div id="ClientRep"></div>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <div id="Manager"></div>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr class="empTableRowBody2">
                <th class="empTableRowBody2">
                    Charge Code
                </th>
                <th class="empTableRowBody2">
                    PO Number
                </th>
                <th class="empTableRowBody2">
                    Work Order
                </th>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    @Html.TextBoxFor(Model => Model.ChargeCode, new { disabled = true })
                </td>
                <td>
                    @Html.TextBoxFor(Model => Model.PONumber, new { disabled = true })
                </td>
                <td>
                    @Html.TextBoxFor(Model => Model.WONumber, new { disabled = true, check = true })
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr class="empTableRowBody2">
                <th class="empTableRowBody2" colspan="3">
                    Job Location
                </th>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td colspan="3">
                    @Html.TextBoxFor(Model => Model.JobLocation, new { @class = "inputWidth500" })
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr class="empTableRowBody2">
                <th class="empTableRowBody2" colspan="3">
                    Job Description
                </th>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td colspan="3">
                    @Html.TextBoxFor(Model => Model.JobDescription, new { @class = "inputWidth500" })
                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </div>
    <div class="section-span-footer"></div>
    <br />
    <div>
        <input type="submit" value="Next" />
    </div>
}
</article>
@section Menu{
@Html.Partial("_MainMenu")
@Html.Partial("_MenuFooter")
}
@section scripts{
@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jqueryval")
@Scripts.Render("~/Scripts/WorkTicket.js")
}
```

I'm sure I'm doing many things wrong as I am new to jQuery and still learning.  Is there a way to disable the autocomplete if the user does not choose an option from the autocomplete widget or if the result of the widget is null?  Thank you in advance!

T.

Comment: Could you please add the relevant HTML/CSS to this question, or create a demo on [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net)?

Comment: Added my html and complete jscript file

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, I finally solved it.  It has nothing to do with autocomplete.  Just goes to show how much I need to learn about jQuery.  I had a bad line of code in my controller where I was saving information about the new work order back to the project.  I was missing one required item and I was just over looking it.  Sorry for being an idiot and ignorant about jQuery.  Thanks anyone that looked.  Can't believe that took me so long to see.......

Comment: Well I hope I can speak for everyone on here and say that we've all been there! The most important point here is that you have knowledge you did not previously have and even better that you solved it yourself. Secondly thanks for posting an answer - you never know who might find this useful in the future. Don't forget you can accept your own answer :-)